# Listviewitem layout

Tags: android, listview, layout

following is my layout used for a ListViewItem in a ListViewActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/list_single" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listUp_RecipeInstructionNumberTextBoxId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/header_orange"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listUp_RecipeInstructioTextTextBoxId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="This is the instruction info"
        android:textSize="14dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="56dp" 
        android:layout_width="63dp" 
        android:id="@+id/listUp_RecipeInstructionImageViewId" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

At first the ImageView is in Visibility = gone. Then user take a picture using a camera and the ImageView visibility is VISIBILE and I update the ImageView to use the taken picture.

In case the TextView is empty - it is shown in the corrent size.
But, when I have a text that gets to the end of the ListViewItem (long text and at first the ImageView is in Visibilite GONE) and then I take the picture, then it is shown in a wrong size. much smaller

How can I fix it?

Comment: please post screenshots for problem you faced. Your explanation is not much good here.

Comment: Can I get screenshots from the device?

Comment: Use emulator and take screenshots

Comment: Yes, goto DDMS, there is a camera icon at the left top side, above the Device Name tab. Get screenshots from there, while the device is connected.

Answer (score 1):

use this `android:layout_weight="1"` for the textview that is large and remove the weight for the imageView.